# Does a 10-K/10-Q report contain an estimate of share market price?

Tags: historical-data, sec, validation

I am trying to find a way to validate available stock market data (because I found so much disagreement between different sources) and went through a 10-K report, hoping to find any mentioning of the market price of common stock of that company (Exxon Mobil in this case). I know that the market price is somewhat irrelevant to a 10-K/10-Q report, but given that these reports are the only really reliable and easily available historical documents about public companies, I hoped to find at least something that can be the basis of an estimate.

The only thing I could find is the "common stock held in treasury"-line in the balance sheet. At least Exxon Mobil mentions both a total dollar amount and a number of shares here. By dividing one through the other, I get an estimate for the share price, which just happens to be close to the market value for the 2021 report. Is this coincidendal, is this usually the case, is there maybe even a GAAP requirement to use the market price for calculating this line?

Edit: I can't answer this question anymore, but as a note partially answering my question: Amgen in its 10-K for 2022 mentions a stock buyback program that contains the average price they paid for the stock they bought. Unfortunately, not every company has a stock buyback program.

Edit2: I eventually found that archives of historical newspapers are a better source of validation. They are available digitally and reach back farther into the past than 10-Q reports (which I think only go back to around 1993 in digital form).

Edit3: Even easier to access (although available only annually, not daily) are SEC-filings of index-tracking ETFs like QQQ (CIK 1067839) and SPY (CIK 884394). Some of the filed reports contain prices for all stocks contained in the underlying index. Cross-checking with the newspaper archives shows these prices to agree.

Comment: No that’s the ‘book value per share’.  The market value is easily obtainable with a simple Google search.

Comment: I am trying to validate what is easily obtainable with a Google search. You can not validate a value with itself.

Answer (score 1):

Market price is many times meaningless (given splits and adjustments). Market cap is more relevant. But the most reliable source is CRSP. If you have access to WRDS that is easily available. Alternatively Bloomberg is also pretty good (though not as good as CRSP data).

Comment: You can not calculate the market cap without knowing the price, which is exactly why I am looking for a reliable source for that. CRSP & WRDS are only available to academic institutions and thus useless to an average Joe.

Comment: That data is usually not free, I am sorry.

Comment: https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/stocks is a free service partly based on the expensive Bloomberg product, so it should be reliable IMO. In my experience https://www.tiingo.com/ and https://www.barchart.com/ are also pretty good (and free). But stay away from Yahoo and Google Finance, I stopped using those.

Comment: Thanks, but that still leaves open my question how I would validate these numbers.